# How to update data in html when variable value varies

Tags: angular

I am working on an angular app where I am displaying data of that variable **this.result** using one way data binding like **{{this.result}}**. When pressing submit, it will call one function which alter value of **this.result**. but it is not changing HTML view. It is showing old data. I guess this is happeing because I need to refresh HTML. For temporary fix I can do **document.getElementById('').innerHTML = 'abcd'**, but I read some where you should not do innerHTML, getElementById in angular.

So, I have 2 question

- How to do instead of DOM Manipulation?
- Why not to do DOM manipulation? isn't it Angular internally uses DOM Manipulation?

I am doing a like button wh

Code snippet:

HTML File

```html
<div style="text-align:right;border-top:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black" [ngClass]="isLiked == true ? 'liked' : 'not-liked'">
   {{ this.likedBy}} liked<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:30px;" aria-hidden="true"  (click)="toggle()"></i>&nbsp;
</div>
```

TypeScript file

```js
toggle()
{
   this.isLiked = !this.isLiked;
   if(this.isLiked === true)
   {
      console.log('You liked this idea now');
      this.likedBy.push(this.adalService.userInfo.profile.email);

   }else{
      console.log('You unliked this idea now');
      this.likedBy.splice(this.likedBy.indexOf(this.adalService.userInfo.profile.email), 1);
   }
   console.log('Latest liker :- ' + this.likedBy)
}
```

In Console, I can see the field value is changing

Comment: Provide code snippet of your html template and your component typescript.

Comment: Here I am  liking and unliking button. It will first check if useremail is not in the  likedBy list and user press like button it will add usermail to that variable, and if user unlike it will remove it from likedBy var

Comment: youd don't need "this" in html  {{ this.likedBy}} -> {{ likedBy }}, another thing "this.likedBy.push" seems to be an array.

Comment: Yeah, this is an array of usermail who liked. And removing this is also working like displaying but not updating still.  "likedBy: String[];"

Comment: @robert is right. It shouldnt be {{this.likedBy}}. remove the "this". it should be {{likedBy}} in HTML.

Comment: And I am making sure that removing function is only called when user already liked otherwise if it can not find usermail it will remove -1th index i.e, last element

Answer (score 2):

> In angular, there is no need to refresh the HTML page for getting the updated value from manipulations in the `.ts`.

I will rewrite your code here with comments so that you understand it better.

HTML

```html
<div style="text-align:right;border-top:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black" [ngClass]="isLiked == true ? 'liked' : 'not-liked'">
  <div *ngFor="let likedByItem of likedBy">
  {{likedByItem}},
  </div> liked<i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:30px;" aria-hidden="true"  (click)="toggle()"></i>&nbsp;
</div>
```

Typescript file

```js
toggle()
{
  this.isLiked = !this.isLiked;
  if(this.isLiked === true)
  {
     console.log('You liked this idea now');
     this.likedBy.push(this.adalService.userInfo.profile.email);
  }
  else
  {
     console.log('You unliked this idea now');
     this.likedBy.splice(this.likedBy.indexOf(this.adalService.userInfo.profile.email), 1);
  }
     console.log('Latest liker :- ' + this.likedBy)
}
// Here likedBy is an array. 
// For displaying this array you have to use *ngFor directive in html.
```

Please comment below if you have any problem understanding this.

Answer (score 0):

I did like this

```
<div style="text-align:right;border-top:1px solid black;border-bottom:1px solid black" [ngClass]="isLiked == true ? 'liked' : 'not-liked'">
    <i class="fa fa-thumbs-up" style="font-size:30px;" aria-hidden="true"  (click)="toggle()"></i>&nbsp;{{ this.likedBy}}
</div>
```

Changing position of variable before  *to after*  is working.

Is it a bug or is there any explanation?